# Add/Delete a string to a pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I need to find a list based on a pattern and add or delete an other string...

I have a xml list of URLs in a file.

In my file, on a single line, I have this :

```
"xml" : "SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE<node n=\"Group1\" u-l=\"toto.com;tata.com;tutu.com\"></node><node n=\"Group2\" u-l=\"bobo.com;baba.com\"></node><node n=\"Group3\" u-l=\"toto.com;papa.com;pepe.com;pupu.com\"></node>SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE"
```

My questions :

1. in Group1 I want to add "newwebsite.com" to my list (at the end of my list)

So `u-l=\"toto.com;tata.com;tutu.com\"` becomes `u-l=\"toto.com;tata.com;tutu.com;newwebsite.com\"`

Of course the only things I know are "Group1" and "newwebsite.com"...

2. in Group3 I want to delete "toto.com" from my list

So `u-l=\"toto.com;papa.com;pepe.com;pupu.com\"` becomes `u-l=\"papa.com;pepe.com;pupu.com\"`

It must not delete "toto.com" from Group1 and I assume that I don't know where "toto.com" is in my Group3 list (position 1 to N possible).

The solutions can be a perl code (working on the file as a filehandler) or a "sed" in the perl code (working with the file directly).
I don't want to put the xml into a hash and work on it (I've tried and basically it works but when we put everything in a file again it's a mess, because of accented characters, newlines, or non utf-8 characters, the output is never matching the input...

Comment: It seems like JSON with XML inside. If that is true, using JSON and XML modules in Perl should help you a lot.

Comment: I know (as I said I'm able to sort everything using the perl modules but special characters always modify the output, that's why I'd like to work on the global file).

Comment: If you are properly using both an XML and a JSON parser this should be relatively straight-forward, as choroba said.

Comment: I did not mention it but the json file quite big (several MBytes) and xml strings in it contain thousand of entries. I would have to parse all the file and recreate a new one (with exactly the same syntax)...I don't see how it can be simplier than a regexp (for the guys who knows regexp better than me). And I still confirm that non utf-8 character a real pain when you read them and write them gain

Comment: If the XML data is real XML, and not something that just resembles XML, it will still mean the same thing when it comes back out. The same goes for the JSON. My experience tells me that this is more of a concern for the XML bit than the JSON bit though. You will be best off using a combination of two parsers, but you will have to at least run it through a JSON parser to get all the escaping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do with just parsing JSON. I doubt it is a good idea to do it without parsing the JSON at all.

I've written an implementation that can modify groups, and add as well as remove domains from them. You need to keep in mind that altering stuff inside XML with regular expressions is always flimsy and naive. It will break easily, as it relies on things being in the right order. It doesn't know about attributes inside the XML tags, or even the tags themselves. It's just a bunch of text.

Having said that, let's first look at the configuration and the actual call.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
my $json =
  q[{"xml" :"SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE<node n=\"Group1\" u-l=\"toto.com;tata.com;tutu.com\"></node><node n=\"Group2\" u-l=\"bobo.com;baba.com\"></node><node n=\"Group3\" u-l=\"toto.com;papa.com;pepe.com;pupu.com\"></node>SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE"}];
my $hash = decode_json $json;
$hash->{xml} = process(
    $hash->{xml} => {
        "Group1" => {add    => [qw/newwebsite.com/]},
        "Group3" => {remove => [qw/toto.com/]}
    },
);
print encode_json($hash);
```

The first assumption is that the string of data you've given us, which looks like JSON, is actually JSON, and that the escaping with the backslashes is verbatim. If that changes, all the code breaks.

There's configuration here that allows you to say you want to `add` and/or `remove` domains from a group.

That's done in the `process` sub, which will iterate the groups, find the first occurrence in the string of XML, and handle it. This assumes the entire XML document is in one line. If there are newlines, this breaks.

Here's the full function.

```perl
sub process {
    my ($xml, $args) = @_;

    foreach my $group (keys %$args) {
        if ($xml =~ m/<node n="\Q$group\E" u-l="([^"]+)">/) {
            my $existing_list = $1;
            my @items = split /;/, $existing_list;

            # remove items from the list
            if (exists $args->{$group}->{remove}) {
                no warnings 'experimental';

                my @remove = @{$args->{$group}->{remove}};
                @items = grep { not $_ ~~ @remove } @items;
            }

            # add new items to the list
            if (exists $args->{$group}->{add}) {
                push @items, @{$args->{$group}->{add}};
            }

            # serialise the list and stick it back in
            # need the "" as an anchor
            my $new_list = join ';', @items;
            $xml =~ s/"(\Q$existing_list\E)"/"$new_list"/;
        }
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

Remember that while this looks like XML, we treat it like just a bunch of text. We need the opening and closing bracket of the `<node>` as an anchor. We grab the list of domains out, and manipulate it. If there is extra whitespace or the order of elements changes, this breaks.

The code uses simple list operations to handle the lists of domains.

To allow easy removal of several domains, this uses the experimental smartmatch operator. You can implement it in a different way, but I was lazy. It will only work on certain Perl version, as this is experimental.

We then stick the new list back into the big string that looks like XML by replacing the old one with it. We need to make sure no special characters (like the dot `.`) make it into the pattern, so we escape it with `\Q` and `\E`.

In case it's not clear yet, I will say it again. While this works for this very specific set of parameters you've given in your question, chances are this will not work fully in production for you. You will have to adapt it, and likely adapt it often.

You are probably better off using both a JSON parser as well as an XML parser.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but I have "Use of uninitialized value $xml in pattern match (m//)". I don't get your call to sub process (there should be 2 parameters, but when you call it, it seems to me there is only one...). the result is : no add in group1, and everything deleted in group3. For information, I made a mistake : ";" is'nt the separator in my file, "&#10;" is the separator (I've put this in the split and the join lines but no success).

Comment: forget my previous comment, there was a second level I didn't see in the json (so it's $hash->{content}->{xml}). I made a mistake : in `<node n` and `" u-l` the separator is not a space but "\n". So when I open the file, all xml is in one line, but when the script reads it it seems "\n" is interepreted (so the websites are not on the same line as "Group1"). the regex never match if it's not one the same line...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works. I am using perl regular expression substitution techniques. I hope I did not misunderstand the question.

```
my $line = '"xml" : "SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE<node n=\"Group1\" u-l=\"toto.com;tata.com;tutu.com\"></node><node n=\"Group2\" u-l=\"bobo.com;baba.com\"></node><node n=\"Group3\" u-l=\"toto.com;papa.com;pepe.com;pupu.com\"></node>SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE"';

my $new_word = "newwebsite.com";
my $remove_word = "toto.com";
print $line;
$line =~ s/(.+)\\\"(Group1\\\" u-l=\\\".+.com)(\\\"\>\<\/node\>\<node n=\\\"Group2.+)(Group3\\\" u-l=\\\".+.com)(.+)/$1.$2.';'.${new_word}.$3.'***'.rm_string($4,$remove_word).$5/e;
print("\n\n$line");


sub rm_string{
    $string = shift;
    $remove_string=shift;
    $string =~ s/$remove_string;?//;
    $string =~ s/;$//;
    return($string);

}
```

the result gives after substitution-

```
"xml" : "SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE<node n=Group1\" u-l=\"toto.com;tata.com;tutu.com;newwebsite.com\"></node><node n=\"Group2\" u-l=\"bobo.com;baba.com\"></node><node n=\"***Group3\" u-l=\"papa.com;pepe.com;pupu.com\"></node>SOMESTUFFWEDONOTCARE"
```

Comment: I focused my time on the previous answer which solved it. But I want to thank you because your answer is also useful to me (pure regex is needed in other raw text files so your regex helps me to understand a bit more how it works on complex pattern matching)

Answer (score 0):

by gnu sed , your data string in 'd' file

```
sed -E 's/(Group1\\.[^>]+)\"(><)/\1;newwebsite.com"\2/i; s/(Group3\\"[^=]+=\\")toto\.com;/\1/i' d
```